# JEST error TypeError: specificMockImpl.apply is not a function

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs

Trying to mock one of the function with callback from api and getting error as `TypeError: specificMockImpl.apply is not a function`

```
import { IEnvironmentMap, load } from 'dotenv-extended';
import { getTokensWithAuthCode, sdk } from '../src/connection-manager';

describe('getTokensWithAuthCode function Tests', () => {

    jest.useFakeTimers();
    let boxConfig: IEnvironmentMap;

    beforeAll(() => {
        boxConfig = load({
            errorOnMissing: true,
        });
    });

    it('should reject a promise if there is wrong auth code provided', async () => {

        sdk.getTokensAuthorizationCodeGrant = jest.fn().mockImplementation(boxConfig.BOX_AUTH_CODE, null, cb => {
            cb('Error', null);
        });

        try {
            const tokens = await getTokensWithAuthCode();
        } catch (error) {
            expect(error).toBe('Error');
        }
    });
});
```

And my function which is trying to test is as follow:

```
import * as BoxSDK from 'box-node-sdk';
import { IEnvironmentMap, load } from 'dotenv-extended';
import {ITokenInfo} from '../typings/box-node-sdk';

const boxConfig: IEnvironmentMap = load({
    errorOnMissing: true,
});

export const sdk: BoxSDK = new BoxSDK({
    clientID: boxConfig.BOX_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: boxConfig.BOX_CLIENT_SECRET,
});

/**
 * - Use the provided AUTH_CODE to get the tokens (access + refresh)
 * - Handle saving to local file if no external storage is provided.
 */
export async function getTokensWithAuthCode() {

    return new Promise((resolve: (tokenInfo: ITokenInfo) => void, reject: (err: Error) => void) => {

        if (boxConfig.BOX_AUTH_CODE === '') {
            reject(new Error('No Auth Code provided. Please provide auth code as env variable.'));
        }

        sdk.getTokensAuthorizationCodeGrant(boxConfig.BOX_AUTH_CODE, null, (err: Error, tokenInfo: ITokenInfo) => {
            if (err !== null) {
                reject(err);
            }

            resolve(tokenInfo);
        });
    });
}
```

Is there any other way to mock function in jest? I have read an article https://www.zhubert.com/blog/2017/04/12/testing-with-jest/

Answer (score 7):

On this line, rather than pass a function to `mockImplementation`, you're passing three arguments:

```
jest.fn().mockImplementation(boxConfig.BOX_AUTH_CODE, null, cb => {
  cb('Error', null);
});
```

It looks like you might have just missed some braces. Try switching it to:

```
jest.fn().mockImplementation((boxConfig.BOX_AUTH_CODE, null, cb) => {
  cb('Error', null);
});
```

Comment: @praveenseela it worked in the context of the original question a couple years ago, but if you're trying to do similar then perhaps the method signature has changed or something in the version you're using. I'd suggest if you're not having any luck it would be best to post a new question detailing what errors you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

It's better not trying to mutate a `const` used elsewhere.
You could change `getTokensWithAuthCode` to make it receive `sdk` as parameter, thus in your test you would pass the mock function as argument, therefore having a more predictable behavior than mutating directly `sdk`.

In your code, you could make a second `getTokensWithAuthCode` implementation, with the signature `getTokensWithAuthCodeUnbound(sdk)` for example, and export it. This implementation will be used in your tests.
Exporting using the same `getTokensWithAuthCode` name, you would call:

```js
export const getTokensWithAuthCode = getTokensWithAuthCodeUnbound.bind(null, sdk)
```

That way, your app will use `getTokensWithAuthCodeUnbound` bound with the default `sdk`, and you can test more easily its implementation.

Mozilla Developer Network (MDN) `bind` [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind).